# Why do the vines change their spinning direction?

Tags: material-science, biophysics

[image]

[image]

Look at the vines holding onto the lattice. The "vine springs" change their spinning direction in the middle. Why? And how do they achieve this?

(I notice that some vines fail to get in touch with the lattice, in such cases they still change direction however)

**Edit: @Danu, I don't think it off topic. I think there is some physics about why they grow this way. I remember reading somewhere about why the springs need to reverse direction in order to maintain zero spin in total (or something like that, the special mechanics of such springs, I don't remember exactly) and how this structure is crucial why the vines are able to pull the plant up efficiently. Unfortunately I can no longer find the source.**

Comment: I'm not sure there is a *physics* reason for this. Or any reason except for "it just grew that way" - or is it the case that you observe this "reversal" in all vines, not just this one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about plant growth, not physics.

Comment: Yes, I think the question of why this grows is not physical.  This is like asking what the physical reason behind an appendix is.  However, I would be for rephrasing the question as something like, "Is this more structurally sound than just a simple spring?"

Comment: @GregPetersen, I would appreciate someone helping me rephrase that way.

Comment: I found out why: https://www.theguardian.com/science/2012/aug/30/secrets-climbing-plants-tendrils   Sorry for my bad wording. English is not my native ; )